# What is the meaning of "lamp" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> See when a girl decides that you're her friend,you're no longer a
>   dating option. You become a complete non-sexual entity in her eyes,
>   like her brother Or a **lamp**.

I'm new to English and have just watched **Just Friends (2005)**. Above quote has a **lamp** word which has another meaning other than electric bulb or source of light.

Comment: The writer is giving an example of an inanimate object. The object could have been a carrot, or a rock, or a bench. The only requirement is that it be  a non-sexual entity. The reference is intended to be humorous.

Comment: @Robusto: Given how precisely Artmal's UD cite (dated 2012) matches the *Just Friends* context, it's tempting to suppose it was actually *prompted* by that usage. Which might otherwise simply have been dismissed as a complete one-off. Interestingly, I found [a related lolcat](http://themetapicture.com/nothing-to-see-here-im-just-a-lamp/) titled ***Nothing to see here, I’m just a lamp*** also posted in 2012. Maybe it has gained or will gain traction, but I kinda doubt it.

Answer (score -1):

From [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Lamp):

An object that oftentimes passes under people's notices. Usually used to describe an object with a light bulb, It can be used to describe an ex-boyfriend who is obscenely annoying and somewhat hated. Once you friend-zone a guy, he becomes a lamp in your mind. A somewhat useless object that can be turned on and sometimes off but is generally a hindrance to daily life. It is much easier to hit the light switch then to use a lamp. Although.... they are always there for backup.... Anyways... no one likes lamps. Except losers.

You can find more definitions on the site.

Comment: The reasons for my downvote: That UD definition has a large number of downvotes, suggesting that many people believe it to be invalid in some way.  You would need to bolster this answer with clear attestations.